# Change face of plain text between double quotation marks in Emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock, emacs-faces

I am looking for a way to highlight or use different face of quoted text in plain text. It seems that there should be a sophisticated/enhanced text mode but I cannot find it.

If there isn't a easy solution, can you let me know where should I begin to write a function?

Thank you very much!

A noob who has been using Emacs from 19.xx

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by quoted? Do you mean "between two "" signs"? Or "block-quoted: indented by spaces"? Or something else?

Comment: The title makes that clearer, @Rupert Swarbrick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about a major-mode that already does this, but you can make one easily enough using define-derived-mode

```
(define-derived-mode rich-text-mode text-mode "Rich Text"
  "text mode with string highlighting."

  ;;register keywords
  (setq rich-text-font-lock-keywords
        '(("\"\\(\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?[^\\]\\)\"" 0 font-lock-string-face)))
  (setq font-lock-defaults rich-text-font-lock-keywords)
  (font-lock-mode 1))
```

Alternatively, you can add a hook to text-mode:

```
(defun add-quotes-to-font-lock-keywords ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\"\\(\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?[^\\]\\)\"" 0 font-lock-string-face))))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'add-quotes-to-font-lock-keywords)
```

Generally speaking, a good mode for editing any text is org-mode.  It does not font-lock strings by default, though.

Answer (score 0):

For the regexp, I think you want to exclude `"` itself in the string content, except when escaped.  Something like this --- `"`, followed by either a non `"` or an escaped character, followed by `"`:

```
\"\\([^\"]\\|\\\\\\(.\\|[\n]\\)\\)*\"
```

But be aware that matching quotations "..." is notorious.  I do exactly that in [***Info+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPlus), but there are a few Info nodes where this highlighting gets thrown off by the occasional lone `\"` or `?\"` in manuals that refer to such programming constructs.