# lisp emacs regex syntax for major modes

Tags: regex, emacs, syntax, elisp, major-mode

I'm trying to learn how to write emacs major-modes.  There are lots of great tutorials online (e.g. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GenericMode), but I'm struggling to learn the syntax for regex matching.  For example, [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165419/230468) I'm trying to understand why

`'(("\"\\(\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?[^\\]\\)\""`

from

```
(define-derived-mode rich-text-mode text-mode "Rich Text"
  "text mode with string highlighting."

  ;;register keywords
  (setq rich-text-font-lock-keywords
        '(("\"\\(\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?[^\\]\\)\"" 0 font-lock-string-face)))
  (setq font-lock-defaults rich-text-font-lock-keywords)
  (font-lock-mode 1))
```

matches anything between double quotation marks.  This material: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special
doesn't seem to explain that.

Are there any better resources out there?

Comment: When presenting a node "Regexp-Special", which obviously covers some special cases, you should be able to look upward at "Syntax of Regexps" rather than down-vote people trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to your question of what the regexp does ---
The regexp in the example you cite is actually `"\"\\(\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?[^\\]\\)\""`.

The parts to match are:

- `\"`, which matches only a `"` char --- this is at the beginning and the end of the regexp.
- A group, which contains `\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?` followed by `[^\\]`.  The group is presumably there so that `font-lock-keywords` can be told to do something with that part of a match, i.e., the part between the matching `"` at the beginning and end.
- `\\(?:.\\|\n\\)*?`, the first part of the group, matches zero or more characters --- any characters.  The `*?` could be just `*` (same thing).  The `.` matches any char except a newline char, and the `\n` matches a newline char.  The `\\|` means either of those is OK.
- `[^\\]` matches any character except a backslash (`\`).

So putting it together, the group matches zero or more chars followed by a char that is not a backslash. Why not just use a regexp that matches zero or more chars between `"` chars? Presumably because the person wanted to make sure the ending `"` was not escaped (by a backslash).  However, note that the regexp requires there to be at least one char between the `"` chars, so that regexp does not match the empty string, `""`.

A good resource is: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression.

Comment: Thanks @Drew, that's extremely helpful!  The resource link you included however, left me confused.  It doesn't explain why `\\ ` work, or the `: `.

Comment: The best reference doc about regexps, which does explain about `\\ ` and `:`, is the Elisp manual. Start with node `Regular Expressions`. Both are explained in node `Regexp Backslash`. See also node `Syntax for Strings` for the use of backslashes in Lisp strings. Remember that `i` in Info is your friend for finding things, and `g` takes you directly to a given node